# day of week function for week day aggregates

Tags: sql, db2

I currently have a query that reads from a table and aggregates based on category. It gives me what I need but I"m trying to add another column that looks at all records for that category/employee combo for the days of this past week. SO if the job with this query runs on Wednesday Night, it needs to get a total of all category/employee records for Monday and Tuesday Night as well.

The query:

```
SELECT employee,
    sum(case when category = 'Shoes' and  date_of_report >=  current_date - 1 days then daily_total else 0 end) as Shoes_DAILY,
    sum(case when category = 'Shoes' and date_of_report >= ( current date - ( dayofweek(current date) - 1 ) days ) then sum(daily_total) else 0 end) as dailyTotalWeek
from shoeTotals
where date_of_report >= current_date
group by employee;
```

So the third column there is what's messing me up saying function use not valid. here's what I want:

The source table has these records for this past week:

```
employee   |   daily_total   |   date_of_report
--------------------------------------------------
123             14                  2019-08-26
123             1                   2019-08-27
123             56                  2019-08-28
123             6                   2019-08-29
123             8                   2019-08-30   * today
```

My desired output would get (based on employee and category) the total for today (8) and then the sum of all the employees' records for that category on each preceding weekday. Running on Monday night would only count that days records, friday night would count monday through friday's as shown above.

```
employee   |   shoes_daily   |    dailyTotalWeek 
--------------------------------------------------
123                 8                85
```

What am I doing wrong with the dayofweek function?

Comment: I'd look at analytic/window functions to me summing your column partitioning by week of year. and then only report on current week of year.

Comment: But this runs nightly, so every night I'll be getting the daily from the explicit record for today, but I just want the 2nd column to sum that value for the days of that week preceding the run date. Is there not a way to do this with dayofweek function

Comment: or do you have suggestions for an analytic function to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot nest aggregation functions.  I think you simply want:

```
select employee,
       sum(case when category = 'Shoes' and date_of_report >=  current_date - 1 days
                then daily_total else 0
           end) as Shoes_DAILY,
       sum(case when category = 'Shoes' and date_of_report >= ( current date - ( dayofweek(current date) - 1 ) days )
                then daily_total else 0
           end) as dailyTotalWeek
from shoeTotals
where date_of_report >= current date - ( dayofweek(current date) - 1 ) days
group by employee;
```

Comment: Ok so that makes sense but it seems to be getting way too many records for that column. There are other categories in the table for each employee and it seems to be getting the totals for all even with the category clause

Comment: The problem seems to be related with Your original query. For "today", you sum with condition "current_date - 1 days" (why two days?), even when Your WHERE clause reads "date_of_report >= current_date". In Gordon Linoff's answer, this discrepancy only gets obvious...